# How to take a user defined function as user input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, user-input

I am trying to write a program to define user-defined function with return expression as input from user.
Suppose a function should return x+y.In python we can do it as---

```
def f(x,y):
 return x+y
```

But,i want something like

```
a=input("enter the function:")
def f(x,y):
  return a
print f(2,3)
```

If i enter x+y as input of a,it will give 5.How can it be done in Python(without Sympy or raw_function along with eval())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) lib parses mathematical expressions.

You can use it like this for example :

```py
from pyparsing import NumericStringParser

nsp = NumericStringParser()
print(nsp.eval('2+3')) # 5
```

You have to replace variables by numeric values.

---

In case your really don't want to use external eval library, an application of [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually easy.Suppose u want to evaluate the function at x=2

```
f1=str(input("Enter the test function:"))
def f(x):
    return eval(f1)
print f(2)
```

That's it!